# Spree install NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spree

I am trying to install the spree store into my `rails` app, and when I enter `spree install` in the terminal, I receive the following error:

```
home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in method_missing': undefined method this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x5c7150 activesupport-4.2.5.1> (NoMethodError)
```

## My gemfile looks like this:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'

gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do

debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do

views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

gem 'spring'
end

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What versions Spree and Rails are you using? What you Gemfile look like?

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem recently after running `bundle update`

Try to downgrade a gemset to 2.5.0 as follows:

```
gem update --system 2.5.0
```

It seems like there is a bug in 2.5.1 version.